# How to disable / change the photoshop cc splash screen (on Mac)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, splash

When you open photoshop cc on mac you get this image: [Photoshop CC Splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J8oH.jpg)

I want to disable it, or (if impossible) to change it to my own image.

I know it's loading stuff, I only want to get rid of the visual image (or change it) - it's not a loading time issue for me.

I also know that is not something you can do by just change some preference but I'm sure there is some kind of a hack that will do it.

Comment: Often splash screens load because they initalise other parts of the application or environment. If you remove it, then this may not mean the app will be ready sooner, and it may not even start up correctly. What actually is the problem with the splash screen?

Comment: It seems this question is formally owned by an unregistered account and you(?) have created another account and attempted to edit the question (I can see the edit in review queue). Read: *[I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)* The point is: as an owner you could edit without peer reviews.

Answer (score 2):

on photoshop shortcut right click properties and in target enter: -NoSplash"

Comment: That's for windows, the question was about Mac.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to do, but possible.

Here is a guide on how to change it on a Mac: https://www.mteam7.com/blog/cc-splash

Note: most of the guide is on how to run the Windows program to convert these files. So if you have a Windows PC available to use, you can skip that part and just do it on the Windows device.

Comment: this link is now broken.
It would have been better to present the steps here, and *reference* the link.

Comment: You're right in principle, but it's a long guide. I updated the link